# Let $\partial A \subseteq L \subseteq A$ and $L = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n {{\gamma _i}} $.Is it true, ${\gamma _i} \subseteq A\backslash \partial A$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ , $\partial A \subseteq L \subseteq A$ , $L = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n {{\gamma _i}} $ and $\partial A\ne \mathbb{C}$ and all $\gamma _i$ are curves
.

Can we say that, all ${{\gamma _i}}$ are subsets of $A\backslash \partial A$?(i.e; ${\gamma _i} \subseteq A\backslash \partial A$ ,$i=1,2,...,n$)

(Note: $\partial A$ is boundary of $A$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ be the top and bottom halves of the unit circle respectively. Then $\partial A$ is the unit circle and clearly contained in $L$ and $L \subset A$. But, $\gamma_i$ is not a subset of the open unit disk (which is $A\setminus \partial A$.)

Comment: Thanks,i edited this post, but the main question, in general, what happened if ${\gamma _i} \subseteq A\backslash \partial A$ , $i=1,2,...,n$?

Comment: This example will still suffice for your edited question.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider the case where A and L are just the same set with one point in it.

Comment: - Thanks,i edited this post, but the main question, in general, what happened if ${\gamma _i} \subseteq A\backslash \partial A$ , $i=1,2,...,n$?